# Unable to parce date exception for incomplete dates

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format

I am having list of date formats which contains only `date and month` or `month and year` or `date and year` not complete dates are available so how to parce these formats

I am using following method to parce date but on some devices getting `Unable to parce date exception`so

**how can we figure out what is missing in date?** so accordingly we can deal.

> Eg. **Sunday, 18th February** I want to parce this date.

Following code is working perfect for valid date formats.

```
List<String> dateFormats = new ArrayList<>();

            dateFormats.add("dd-MM");
            dateFormats.add("d-MM");
            dateFormats.add("MM yyyy");
            dateFormats.add("EEEE, dd'th' MMMM");

     for (int i = 0; i < dateFormats.size(); i++) {

            try {
                SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormats.get(i), Locale.ENGLISH);
                d.setLenient(false);
                diff = new Date().getTime() - d.parse(value).getTime();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (i == dateFormats.size() - 1)
                    e.printStackTrace();
                diff = 0;
            }

        }
```

Comment: can you check for which devices you are getting the exception? maybe they have a different date format which you are not using

Comment: @ArpitSharma I am having `Oppo 6.0 ,MI 7.0 and MI 8.1.0` on oppo code working perfect getting default year 1970 and date and month it will take Jan/1 I am Ok with it. `MI 7.0 and above` having issue

Comment: You have incomplete dates (without year) and specify lenient=false. That causes exception.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk So What need to do here?

Comment: @SagarHudge Two options: 1. To set lenient="true", which is default. 2. To concat the year to the value and to dateFormats strings.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk I will try for lenient=true  to  `concat` I am having list of dates and diff. formats not sure which date format will get.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk thank you for help. `lenient=true`  will affect on other `correct formats` I am having list of dates and formats.